# How to access existing GRAILS application with REST

Tags: web-services, grails

Hi am just started working on grails.. developed my first application in grails can any one suggest me how to access my web application with REST messages...

Comment: Your question shows a dire lack of effort. Please try at least googling your question before coming here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [Docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#REST).

In short, add a URL-mapping like

```
"/product/$id"(controller: "product") {
    action = [GET: "show", PUT: "update", DELETE: "delete", POST: "save"]
}
```